# How to check if cell is formatted as Currency?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am working on a project where it is necessary to check that a large number of cells meet a number of criteria.

I have been able to use the code below to check whether a cell contains a value in a numeric format. However, I also need a way to check whether a cell contains a value formatted as US Currency.

```
If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Range(StringColumn & StringRow).Value) Then  
    MsgBox "Test Failed at " & StringColumn & StringRow  
    Exit Sub  
Else: MsgBox "Valid format for cell " & StringColumn & StringRow  
End If
```

StringColumn and StringRow are variables that supply the cell reference.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using `$` as your currency, you can try this:

```
Dim strFormat as String

strFormat = Range(StringColumn & StringRow).NumberFormat

If InStr(1,strFormat,"$") = 0 Then  'not a currency format

    MsgBox "Test Failed at " & StringColumn & StringRow  
    Exit Sub  

Else: MsgBox "Valid format for cell " & StringColumn & StringRow  

End If
```

If you have another currency, replace the `$` with your currency symbol.

Comment: Works great - thanks! Also, as it turns out I have a mix of Currency and Accounting formats, I found I could use "_($" in place of "$" for Accounting.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) equivalent of the formulae
`=CELL("format",A1)`
which starts with `C` for currency or accounting formats

```
MsgBox Left$(Evaluate("CELL(""Format"",A1)"), 1) = "C"
```

Comment: Thanks! I always forget how much can be done with Evaluate(). In this case the first answer was more helpful as it lets me distinguish between Currency and Accounting.