# How to put UTF-8 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, unicode, utf-8

is it possible to put a unicode character in the codepane in Excel 2013?

Like this:

```
Select Case Work(str)
   Case "◊ Engineering", "◊ Woodworking", "◊ Technician"
   'Do Something
End Select
```

Comment: Note: UTF-8 is one of several character encodings for the Unicode character set. Another is UTF-16. Excel and VBA use UTF-16 natively (since the 1990s). (But unfortunately, as you've found, the VBA editor does not use Unicode). Therefore, this question has nothing to do with UTF-8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type Unicode currency character in Visual Basic Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384952/how-to-type-unicode-currency-character-in-visual-basic-editor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `ChrW` function for that:

```
Select Case Work(str)
   Case ChrW(9674) & " Engineering", ChrW(9674) & " Woodworking", ChrW(9674) & " Technician"
   'Do Something
End Select
```

you can test this e.g. as follows:

```
Sheet1.[A1].Value = ChrW(9674)
```

This will put your character in cell `A1` of `Sheet1`

Comment: The `ChrW` CharCode argument is a `Long` that identifies a character, but doesn't allow values greater than 65535 (hex value `&HFFFF`). You can find six systematic ways to overcome this restriction at [Get UniCode characters with CharCode greater hex `FFFF`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008191/get-unicode-characters-with-charcode-values-greater-hex-ffff)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Chr or ChrW Functions.

The valid range for Chr is 0 through 255, and the valid range for ChrW is -32768 through 65535.

Example:

```
ChrW(9608)
```

or

```
ChrW(&H2588)
```

The &H preface says that 2588 is a hexadecimal number, which is what you find looking at charmap.