# WIndows/VBA: special characters are not recognized any more

Tags: vba, windows

i have a new PC, WIN10 again, same programs (Office2013) again, nothing changed more or less. But: i have a program to copy the path of a file into the clipboard, these links d not work if there are special characters in the filename (ÖÄÜ...).
Also in VBA my "personal.xlsb" does not open, i get a error with title "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" and as text only "400".
Some other vba-macros dont work as soon as a table has a ÜÖÄ in its name. When I enter ?"Ä" in the direct window, i get "ï¿½" as solution.

I have checked the obvious language settings and dont know where to search anymore...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your "Language for non-unicode programs" under Region/Administrative is a language that can handle the special characters. Run intl.cpl to open it.

You can use [ChrW()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function) to wright your special characters.

Comment: wow that was well hidden, and a "beta" I never opted in.... The problem is caused in the enhanced regional settings, there is a point "Beta: Unicode UTF-8 for support of worldwide languages" Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

OK - this was tricky since not all special characters could be pasted into VBA due to my language settings.  To bypass this, I created a UserForm with 2 labels.  Each label contains the before/after string of characters as follows:

Form2.Label1.Caption is
ÁáÁÀàÂâÄäÃãÅåčČÇçďĎÐðÉéÉÈèÊêËëěĚÍíÍÌìÎîÏïľňŇÑñÓóÓÒòÔôÖöÕõřŘŠšŠťŤÚúÚÙùÛûÜüůŮÝýÝŸŽžŽ

Form2.Label2.Caption is
AaAAaAaAaAaAacCCcdDDdEeEEeEeEeeEIiIIiIiIilnNNnOoOOoOoOoOorRSsStTUuUUuUuUuuUYyYYZzZ

Here is the sub that replaces special characters (text with diacritics, accents, carons/hačeks ( ˇ ) in the Selected text:

```vb
Sub ReplaceAccentedChar()
'UserForm2 is used to store all special characters since they can't be used in VBA code (some don't copy/paste correctly)

    Dim sFm As String
    Dim sTo As String
    Dim i As Long

    sFm = UserForm2.Label1.Caption
    sTo = UserForm2.Label2.Caption
    
    For i = 1 To Len(sFm)
        Selection.Cells.Replace Mid(sFm, i, 1), Mid(sTo, i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
    Next i

End Sub
```

Inspiration came from Joao Casqueiro's post on the Microsoft Community web pages, but this included those special characters the VBA can't even handle.

Comment: `UserForm2 is used to store all special characters` - really? [All 149878](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) of them? Please see https://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html, then https://stackoverflow.com/q/24384952/11683.