# Why does Word (2007) mess up this Unicode character in a macro?

Tags: vba, unicode, ms-word

NB I have looked at other questions on this topic. In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25260658/595305) works fine to produce the symbol there ("Rs"), and other characters, such as East Asian ideograms, also work fine.

NB this is Word **2007**. If you find that the above-linked method works for you for the character I need (see below), with a newer version of Word, that would be of interest to know about.

The character I need is **⏑**, Metrical Breve, Unicode 23D1 (9169 decimal), from the Miscellaneous Technical block.

I can produce this in the file, manually, using this method:

- ensure Num Lock is on
- hold down Alt key
- using the numeric keypad, type +09169
- release Alt key

... but to date I can find no way whatsoever to incorporate this into a working Word 2007 macro: `ChrW(&H23D1&)` gets printed as a generic "Don't recognise this" block (small rectangle).

Comment: `Selection.TypeText ChrW(&H23D1)` is properly working with Word 2019, font `Segoe UI Symbol`

Comment: In my Windows 10, the only fonts capable to render the `⏑` _Metrical Breve_ are `Segoe UI Symbol`, `Unifont` and `Unifont CSUR`.

Comment: Your macro needs to apply a font that includes the symbol you want. IIRC`Segoe UI Symbol` was introduced with Windows 8.

Comment: Thanks... yes, I examined the font of Metrical Breve input manually and to my surprise, since it was input into a run of Consolas text, this has the font "MS Mincho". If I try the macro with `ChrW(&H23D1&)` in the middle of a run of "MS Mincho" text, it does indeed input the thing correctly. So it appears to be a question of what particular fonts are and are not capable of...