# Split Arabic name characters and store the results in an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Arabic name and I am trying to split the Arabic characters and at the same time to identify the character if First, Middle or Last
Here's my try but I couldn't fix the code

```
Sub Split_Arabic_Name()
    Dim sName As String, i As Long
    sName = "حاتم علاء خميس سيد"
    Dim result() As String
    Dim index As Integer
    index = 0
    For i = 1 To Len(sName)
        If AscW(Mid(sName, i, 1)) >= &HD800 And AscW(Mid(sName, i, 1)) <= &HDBFF Then
            ReDim Preserve result(index)
            result(index) = Mid(sName, i, 2)
            index = index + 1
            i = i + 1
        Else
            If Mid(sName, i, 1) <> " " Then
                ReDim Preserve result(index)
                result(index) = Mid(sName, i, 1)
                index = index + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Dim arrName() As String
    ReDim arrName(0 To UBound(result), 0 To 1)
    Dim first As Integer, middle As Integer, last As Integer
    first = 0
    middle = 0
    last = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(result)
        arrName(i, 0) = result(i)
        If (i = 0) Or (Mid(sName, i + 1, 1) = " ") Then
            arrName(i, 1) = "First"
        ElseIf Mid(sName, i + 1, 1) = " " Then
            arrName(i, 1) = "Last"
        Else
            arrName(i, 1) = "Middle"
        End If
    Next i
    Range("H1").Resize(UBound(arrName, 1) + 1, UBound(arrName, 2) + 1).Value = arrName
End Sub
```

The spaces are considered as marks. While the name starts with ح so this is [First] -- then  ا then ت [these are Middle] --- then م followed be space so this is [Last]

the second name after space which is ع , should be [First] -- then the characters  ل then  ا [Middle] --- and the character ء [Last] as it is before the space .. and so on

as for the last name سيد , the [First] is س but ي [Middle] --and the last character in the whole name not followed be space but it is the last character so it is [Last]

This is a snapshot of the results I got and I typed the remarks
[image]

Comment: `sName = "حاتم علاء خميس سيد"` - you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25260658/11683) really do that in the VBA editor. Put that text to a cell and read it from there.

Comment: So what's the difference? The code works partially as the first column of results is correct. The problem is with how to set the position of each character.

Comment: I'd recommend a solution with regex. Just loop over matches when using a pattern like `"(?:^|\s)(\S)|(\S)(?!\s|$)|(\S)(?=\s|$)"`. I'm not able to test it in VBA because of the reason @GSerg mentioned, but I do believe there is some merit to the idea. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/JpxOog/1) is an online demo to show you how it 'could' look when looping through.

Comment: Great idea. But I am not working on regex a lot. Can you provide me with the code if possible? But the number of the parts are not constant. Each part of the name is separated by space but the number of name parts are not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, a regular expression might not be a bad idea here:

```
Sub Test()

Dim s As String: s = [A1]
Dim x As Long: x = 1
Dim tst As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(?:^|\s)(\S)|(\S)(?!\s|$)|(\S)(?=\s|$)"
    Set matches = .Execute(s)
    If Not matches Is Nothing Then
        For Each Match In matches
            x = x + 1
            tst = Match.Submatches(0) & Match.Submatches(1) & Match.Submatches(2)
            Select Case tst
                Case Match.Submatches(0)
                    Cells(x, 2).Value = "First"
                Case Match.Submatches(1)
                    Cells(x, 2).Value = "Middle"
                Case Match.Submatches(2)
                    Cells(x, 2).Value = "Last"
            End Select
            Cells(x, 1).Value = tst
        Next
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

The idea behind the pattern `(?:^|\s)(\S)|(\S)(?!\s|$)|(\S)(?=\s|$)` is to catch every character other than whitespace as a seperate match in their own respective group. The regex engine does recognize that it needs to read the input right to left. To break this pattern down:

- `(?:^|\s)(\S)` - A single non-whitespace character that is preceded by the start of the input **or** a whitespace character;
- `(\S)(?!\s|$)` - A non-whitespace character **not** followed by a whitespace character nor the end-line. This does catch the correct characters apart from the first character because of the order or the alternations in the pattern;
- `(\S)(?=\s|$)` -  A non-whitespace character that **is** followed by a whitespace character nor the end-line. This does catch the correct characters apart from the first character because of the order or the alternations in the pattern.

So each match in group 1 is a 'First', each match in group 2 is 'Middle' and each match in group 3 is 'Last'.

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpxOog/1)